# location element for web.config security when path is is empty "" and not "."

Tags: c#, security, web-config

I'm using one of the nightly resharper builds and recently I just came across it pointing out this message "Location element is unusued: path is empty" given the following web.config code

```
 <location path="">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I find this statement from resharper to be dubious being that I have used location elements like this without issue.

Is the blank path just defaulting it to `"."` as the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx) says is the default value of the path property?

Making `<location path="">` and `<location path=".">` functionally equivalent?

Comment: path="" shouldn't throw an exception. I am not familiar with resharper but did you try something in a separate application and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is surely another example of Resharper's over-zealousness. Microsoft advise to use a blank path in the [breaking changes for ASP.NET 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes).

However according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx),

> Using location with a missing path attribute applies the configuration settings to the current directory and all child directories.

so you can possibly just omit the path attribute, which prevents the Resharper error.

Comment: It always a good day when I can accept an answer for a question I asked nearly a year ago.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for `path` is `"."` only when you don't override it; this, `<location>` is functionally equivalent to `<location path=".">` - but `<location path="">` is different. A blank path though isn't *supposed* to get used; if it ever gets used, that's very likely a bug in the way .net treats empty paths.

Comment: I really want some validation to this answer, especially your last sentence that is the entire purpose of this question.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty for being the only person attempting to answer the question instead of allowing it to expire. However I still cannot accept this answer currently without any supporting information.

Comment: Thanks. I'd give you supporting information if I had it, but I don't - this is just my understanding of how web.config works.